# Extract hostname from fully qualified domain name (FQDN)

Tags: c#, host, fqdn

I need to implement a method which extracts a hostname from FQDN. For example if a hypothetical mail server is `mymail.somecollege.edu` I want to get as a result `mymail`
And if I get illegal string (not real `FQDN`) need no get `null` or some error code
How can I extract hostname?-
I don`t want to make a parsing of the input by myself.But rather looking for existing API.
Thanks
I tried to search for the first dot '.' - substring before it is a hostname.
But I am looking for existing API

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you or suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, do you have access to the domain name? (either fixed or possible to retrieve) IIRC, an FQDN is of the format "{hostname}.{domain}". Either placeholder could contain "." characters of their own, but if you know the domain, you should be able to subtract that from the FQDN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get specific subdomain from URL in foo.bar.car.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734769/get-specific-subdomain-from-url-in-foo-bar-car-com)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any helper/API class to obtain the hostname (mymail) from the FQDN (mymail.somecollege.edu).  You may have to just parse it like you mentioned:  Extract everything up to the first "." character.  NOTE: hostnames are not allowed to contain "." character.

```
var fullyQualifiedDomainName = Dns.GetHostEntry("computer").HostName;
var hostName = fileComputerName.Substring(0, fullyQualifiedDomainName 
    .IndexOf("."));
```