# How to parse domain and subdomain (if it exists) from a URL using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

What is the best way to parse the domain and optionally, the subdomain, out of a URL using C#.  The solution should also work with "localhost" so that the same code can be used in local development as in production.

Examples and Expected Results:

```
    http(s)://yahoo.com -> domain:yahoo.com | subdomain:
    http(s)://test.yahoo.com -> domain:yahoo.com | subdomain:test
    http(s)://test.testing.yahoo.com -> domain:yahoo.com | subdomain:test.testing
    http(s)://localhost:55555 -> domain:localhost | subdomain:
    http(s)://test.localhost:55555 -> domain:localhost | subdomain:test
    http(s)://test.testing.localhost:55555 -> domain:localhost | subdomain:test.testing
    http(s)://yahoo.com.uk -> domain:yahoo.com.uk | subdomain:
    http(s)://test.yahoo.com.uk -> domain:yahoo.com.uk | subdomain:test
```

Comment: What defines a `subdomain` here? Your examples seem pretty arbitrary.

Comment: This thread gives a possible extension method for your needs:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734769/get-specific-subdomain-from-url-in-foo-bar-car-com

Comment: I like the extension method.  Not sure if it works with my localhost scenario.  DavidG mentions another scenario where you have multi-part domains that may not work with it.  I'll have to play with it and see.

Comment: The last two items in your list confuses me.

Comment: in your samples, are you sure the test.testing is a valid sub-domain? I think sub-domain cannot have "." or "/"

Comment: For determining top level domains (1tld), paired with 2nd TLD (if appropriate), you could use this list available at https://publicsuffix.org/list/ (just click "See the list" link). There are a lot more *top level* domains, that consist of both 1st level and 2nd level domains.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to determine what your subdomains are for example:

```
www.yahoo.com
www2.yahoo.com
```

Are `www` and `www2` subdomains? Also what about `newcastle.sch.uk`? That is a domain, not a subdomain. And how about the new `.uk` top level domain?

As for the other components, I would use the [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class like this:

```
var url = "http://someuser@test.somedomain.com:1234";
var uri = new Uri(url);

Console.WriteLine(uri.Host);
Console.WriteLine(uri.Port);
Console.WriteLine(uri.Scheme);
Console.WriteLine(uri.UserInfo);
```

This will output:

```
test.somedomain.com
1234
http
someuser
```

Comment: As to your first question: Yes, www and www2 would both be considered subdomains.  As for your second question, good point.  In that scenario the domain should come back "newcastle.sch.uk" and the subdomain empty.

Comment: The main thrust of my point is these are just a couple of examples off the top of my head. To guarantee you work out what is a subdomain means you need to know what all of the top level domains are.