# Get CName in Code-Behind C#

Tags: c#, cname

I have a generic website called **portal.com**.

For each client, I will generate a custom website using CName, such as:

- **client1**.portal.com
- **client2**.portal.com
- **client3**.portal.com

All will be redirected to portal.com. Arriving at **something**.portal.com website, I would like to take **something** to perform a custom action.

Does anyone know how to get this CName?

Comment: you can't just do a left on the host name?

Comment: or String.Split()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get specific subdomain from URL in foo.bar.car.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734769/get-specific-subdomain-from-url-in-foo-bar-car-com)

Comment: That's generally called the subdomain. The [CNAME is the "canonical name"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) and can be any name that is redirected to from another name. See also [Difference between CNAME and SUBDOMAIN](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/60133)

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you just want the domain

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

If you want the port number too, you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Uri.Authority
```