# Asp Net c# get full host with cname?

Tags: c#

How can I get the full host or full URL with a site configurated with a cname?

For example, I have a website which URL is http://shop.gv.com.

With the cname I get a website like http://en.shop.gv.com

When I use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host, I only get http://shop.gv.com.

How can I get the full one?
I works if I use the JavaScript function `window.location.hostname`.

Answer (score 0):

use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` to get the full path
or you can refer to this link for a better approach [sub domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734769/get-specific-subdomain-from-url-in-foo-bar-car-com)

Comment: Thanks but i need the domain showed in the url. With the javascript function (window.location.hostname) i get en.shop.gv.com but with the request.url.host i only get shop.gv.com , the "en" part is missing

Comment: check my link mentioned in the answer,